# import error while trying to run django on apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, django-wsgi

I am trying to run my `django` project on an `apache` server. I am not running the `django` project on a `virtualenv`. I have the following piece of code in `views.py` where I get an ***import error*** saying ***No module named startInsight*** every time. The same if I run with `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80` it works prefectly fine.

Error point in `views.py`:

```
sys.path.insert(0,"/Insight/scripts")
import startInsight
```

The following are the configurations I made:-

/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /web/mysite
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /web/mysite>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /static /web/mysite/mysite/static
    <Directory /web/mysite/mysite/static>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /web/mysite/mysite>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                    Require all granted
            </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIDaemonProcess mysite python-path=/usr/bin/python:/web/mysite
    WSGIProcessGroup mysite
    WSGIScriptAlias / /web/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

/web/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py:

```
import os
'''
I tried adding these two lines below. Did not make a difference.
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/Insight/scripts")
'''
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong and would need some guidance.

Comment: Is your script really in a directory off the root called "Insight"? If so, why? And why aren't you using a virtualenv?

Comment: Yes.It is in a folder in root called 'Insight'. The location of it was previously decided by another developer and has some dependencies to its path and wish not to change its location. Should that cause an issue with apache?

Comment: What is the **FULL PATH** to `startInsight.py`? What version of python are you using?

Comment: On `WSGIDaemonProcess` you can add `Insight/scripts` to `python-path=...:...:...:...` instead of tweaking with `sys.path`

Comment: The full path for `startInsight.py` is  `/Insight/scripts/startInsight.py`... I tried adding `/Insight/scripts` to `WSGIDaemonProcess`... Still getiing the same error...

Comment: Check that the user that Apache runs your code as has access to the files/directories. The ``python-path`` option should not be getting set to ``/usr/bin/python``, although that in itself wouldn't cause the problem.

Comment: I changed the owner to apache... It is working now... Thank you! @GrahamDumpleton